# Query string gets automatically removed from header in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When I hit this url https://www.cordly.io?fpr=morten48 the query param fpr=marten48 automatically gets removed from the header how can i prevent that ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Next 13 with app dir. In that case, is very likely you are facing this [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43077).

You can fix it by adding 'force-dynamic' on your page.tsx:

```js
// Add this line to fix the query params issue
export const dynamic='force-dynamic';

export default function Page(props) {
  return (
    <div>
       {JSON.stringify(props.searchParams, null, 2)}
    </div>
  )
}
```